# What does the strikethrough text in the Gipsy Danger schematics say?

Tags: pacific-rim

The Pacific Rim fan community often discuss the Jaeger blueprint diagrams like [this](https://static.squarespace.com/static/51b3dc8ee4b051b96ceb10de/51ce6099e4b0d911b4489b79/51ce61c7e4b0d911b44a08fd/1354134256307/1000w/JaegerGipsyDanger.jpeg). There is a strikethrough text in the Gipsy Danger diagram, below the nuclear vortex turbine. I cannot read it completely. Does anybody known the content of this text and why it has been striked through?

Comment: I would go so far as to say "yes, anybody can". You might want to reword the title :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Health checks returned radio chemical readings in excess of safety parameters see log 3.21_Oct16

Specifically why it was struck through is unclear. The art book does not make any mention, nor is there any hint in the novelization. This is likely just to make it look like an updated notation.